# PHP Mail Function not sending from Gmail Addresses

Tags: php, forms, email, gmail

I'm trying to get this contact form working and it doesn't seem to be able to send with headers saying it is from a gmail address I feel like yahoo addresses were also in the mix of ones that didn't work. Here is the code that seems like it would matter to this. If the host matters I am on Dreamhost. Let me know please.

```
    if(!is_array($contact_information_type))
{
    $contact_information_type = Array();
}

if($_POST){
    $contact_name = trim(stripslashes($_POST["contact_name"]));
    $contact_company = trim(stripslashes($_POST["contact_company"]));
    $contact_address1 = trim(stripslashes($_POST["contact_address1"]));
    $contact_address2 = trim(stripslashes($_POST["contact_address2"]));
    $contact_city = trim(stripslashes($_POST["contact_city"]));
    $contact_state = trim(stripslashes($_POST["contact_state"]));
    $contact_zip = trim(stripslashes($_POST["contact_zip"]));
    $contact_country = trim(stripslashes($_POST["contact_country"]));
    $contact_phone = trim(stripslashes($_POST["contact_phone"]));
    $contact_fax = trim(stripslashes($_POST["contact_fax"]));
    $contact_email = trim(stripslashes($_POST["contact_email"]));
    $contact_comments = trim(stripslashes($_POST["contact_comments"]));
if($contact_name == ""){ $errors_array[] = "Name is required."; }
if($contact_company == ""){ $errors_array[] = "Company name is required."; }
        if($contact_city == "") { $errors_array[] = "City is required."; }

if($contact_state == ""){ $errors_array[] = "State is required."; }




if($contact_country == "") { $errors_array[] = "Country is required.";}
elseif($contact_country == "United States" ) 
{if($contact_zip != "" && !preg_match("/(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/", $contact_zip)){       $errors_array[] = "Incorrect Zip. (e.g. 60660 or 60660-1234)"; };}
elseif($contact_country == "Canada" ){if($contact_zip != "" && !preg_match("/^[ABCEGHJ-    NPRSTVXY]{1}[0-9]{1}[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]{1}[ ]?[0-9]{1}[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$/i",     $contact_zip)){ $errors_array[] = "Incorrect Zip. (e.g. M4C 1B5 or M4C1B5)"; };}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                else {;}






    if($contact_phone == ""){ $errors_array[] = "Phone is required."; }
    if($contact_phone != "" && !preg_match("/(^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$)|  (^\d{10}$)/", $contact_phone)){ $errors_array[] = "Incorrect Phone. (e.g. 123-123-1234)"; }
    if($contact_fax != "" && !preg_match("/(^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$)|(^\d{10}$)/",   $contact_fax)){ $errors_array[] = "Incorrect Fax. (e.g. 123-123-1234)"; }
    if($contact_email == ""){ $errors_array[] = "E-mail is required."; }
    if($contact_email != "" && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.  [a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/", $contact_email)){ $errors_array[] = "Incorrect E-mail. (e.g.   youremail@domain.com)"; }
if($contact_comments == ""){ $errors_array[] = "Comments are required."; }
    if(sizeof($errors_array) == 0){
        $contact_information_type = implode(", ",     $contact_information_type);

$email_message = <<<MESSAGE
The contact form on www.rotaryvalve.com has been filled out with the following information:


Name: ${contact_name}
Company: ${contact_company}
Address 1: ${contact_address1}
Address 2: ${contact_address2}
City: ${contact_city}
State: ${contact_state}
Zip: ${contact_zip}
Country: ${contact_country}
Phone: ${contact_phone}
Fax: ${contact_fax}
E-mail: ${contact_email}
Comments/Products of Interest: ${contact_comments}
MESSAGE;

        $email_adds = array("sales-team@wmwmeyer.com", "dan@danbaran.com");
        $email_from = $contact_email;
        $email_subject = "Customer Request/Comment";
        foreach($email_adds as $email_to){
            mail ($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, "From: ".$email_from." <".$email_from.">");
        }
```

essentially if the contact_email filled out on the form(code not included sorry didn't think you'd need it but let me know if you do) is a gmail account it doesn't seem to send it please help me out on this one.

Comment: As far as I can tell it isn't which is why I have it set to go to 2 different email address on there. I've checked both of their junk boxes and nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Is the problem not being sent, or not being received. I'm pretty sure that the problem is not the email being sent, but what happens when it gets received by the receiver's email service. It may be classed as spam, because they can see it is not sent from the GMail mailservers.

Comment: Couldn't really tell you which it is. I have the exact same code over on a different server so I ran that and it sent me the email so I am wondering if it is Dreamhost more than anything else but I'm not really sure I am hoping someone has some advice on this

Comment: Well, the whole situation was not exactly clear, but I recommend using Michal Charemza's advice.

Answer (score 1):

The email may be classed as spam by the receiving server or client, due to SPF records on the gmail.com domain that will most likely mark the emails as spam.

You would however be able to send the email with a 'Reply-To' header of the email entered in the contact form. This would give the email a better chance of getting past spam filters, and if the recipient hits the "Reply" button in their client, the email will default to being sent to this address.